# Is Loki a Eldþursar?

Tags: norse, interpretation, loki

I fully aware that Loki is no longer considered a fire god, but I recently read an interesting [two](http://polytheist.com/orgrandr-lokean/2014/09/17/a-new-place-for-loki-part-i/)-[part](http://polytheist.com/orgrandr-lokean/2014/09/23/a-new-place-for-loki-part-ii/) article proposing that Loki is an *Eldþursar* (Fire Giant). The article does this by analysing archaeological evidence, extracts from Old Norse poems where Loki is associated with fire and comparing Loki with Indo-European fire deities  such as Hēphaistos/Volcānus (Greco-Roman mythology) and Agní (Vedic Hinduism).

Is there any element of truth  in this article?

Comment: My understanding is there's a theory he might be a form of the fire giant [Logi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logi), and I don't think it's a stretch to connect his name to the PIE root [*lewk-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/luk-) which means "bright".

Comment: @DukeZhou So, basically like... *"Lewk, I am your father!"* SCNR :)

Comment: @Mario lol, yup!